# Where are the settings for stock swype?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, swype, input-methods

I have a Samsung Galaxy S from Sprint that has Swype pre installed. The latest OS update included some changes to Swype that are making me completely insane. The biggest issue is that it auto-corrects words when I'm finger tapping accurately. So a message to my sister that meant to say "Pfft. Just come." got auto corrected to "Orgy. Just come." I'm totally exasperated!

I can't find Swype settings on my phone. I looked at http://www.swype.com/tips/swype-basics/ but the only thing I get when I longpress the Swype key is the option to toggle between input methods. I can't access any further settings.

Comment: Seems "language and keyboard" is "locale and text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Settings > Language and keyboard > Swype` on a Galaxy S2

Comment: They're under `Settings > Locale and Text > Swype` for me.